# Dr. Lamport's Unfinished Business

Tags: code-golf, array, bitwise

## Introduction

Dr. Leslie Lamport, of the eponymous [Lamport one-time signature scheme](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2016/12/Constructing-Digital-Signatures-from-a-One-Way-Function.pdf), is getting rather old. But he can't die until his most famous algorithm gets all the kinks ironed out!

In particular, that scheme had one internal component he was never satisfied with:

> We hope that someone can find a more elegant method for constructing the function `G`

## Challenge

Today, we're helping him prepare to leave by constructing a function `R` that takes the output of our one-way function `φ` (likely a hash function), and injectively uses it to **select a subset** of the user's private key, according to the following specifications:

- Your function takes two arguments: the output of hash function `φ` (as a data blob, octet stream, or similar appropriate native datatype), and an ordered set (in your choice of appropriate native datatype).

  - If your language's **standard library** has a bitstring datatype [[ex: Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html); [*not* Python](https://pypi.org/project/bitstring/)], you **may** choose to take `d` as it with no penalty; if it does not, then unpacking the bytestring (or finding some clever way to avoid or vectorize the doing-of!) is your responsibility.
- The `n`th bit of `φ`'s output chooses whether the `2*n`th element or the `2*n+1`th element will be included in the subset. If `φ` outputs a 24-bit data blob, then 24 elements will be chosen.

  - FOR EXAMPLE: if the **second** bit of `φ(m)` is 1, then the **fourth** element of `pk` will be chosen. If this bit is, instead, 0, then the **third** element of `pk` will be chosen. (There are examples included below.)
  - Naturally, for 1-indexed languages, the `n`th bit chooses between the `2*n-1`th and `2*n`th elements.
  - behavior is **totally undefined** in the event that `φ` returns something with more bits than half the number of elements in `pk`; don't even consider this case.
- Your function returns the thus-chosen subset of `pk`.

  - While the *input* set is ordered, the *output* set does **not need to be ordered** (and, if it is an ordered datatype, all possible orderings are allowed with no penalty). The function merely has to identify a *subset* of the ordered input set, so any ordering on its output would be redundant anyway.
- This is a standard golfing challenge; shorter answers are better than longer answers.

## Example Input and Output

For all examples,
`N = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64`

- φ = MD5, with the digest truncated to the first 24 bits
  m = [empty string]
  φ(m) -> `\xd4\x1d\x8c`

  - R(φ(m), `N`) -> `2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 24, 26, 28, 29, 32, 34, 35, 37, 39, 42, 44, 45, 47`
- φ = CRC32
  m = "Hello, World" (ASCII)
  φ(m) -> `\x26\x5b\x86\xc6`

  - R(φ(m), `N`) -> `1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 12, 14, 15, 17, 20, 21, 24, 26, 27, 30, 32, 34, 35, 37, 39, 41, 44, 46, 47, 50, 52, 53, 55, 57, 60, 62, 63}`
- d = `\x00\x00` = two bytes, with all bits "off"

  - R(d, `N`) -> `1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31`
- d = `\xFF` = one byte, with all bits "on"

  - R(d, `N`) -> `2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16`
- φ = Constant function returning the single byte `\x1d`
  m = [any input]

  - R(φ(m), `N`) -> `1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12, 13, 16`

---

### Python 3, 281 bytes:

(281 does not include comments, type hints, docstrings, or the example φ)

```python
def _iterbits(data):
    yield from (((byte & (0b1 << k)) >> k) for byte in data for k in reversed(range(8)))

def R(digest: bytes, pk: OrderedSet | list | tuple) -> set:
    "Reference solution"
    included_indices = set(2 * n + bit for n, bit in enumerate(_iterbits(digest)))
    return set(k for i, k in enumerate(pk) if i in included_indices)

def φ(m):
    "Example hash function to help you run your own test cases\n\nReturns an MD5 digest truncated to 24 bits"
    return hashlib.md5(m).digest()[:3]
```

Comment: Can we just take an array of bits for the output of `φ`? Also, it would be much easier to just include the output of φ(m) in the test cases since computing it is not part of the challenge anyway.

Comment: Arnauld's suggestion would make this challenge more awesome.

Comment: @Arnauld So you're proposing that (for the Python example given), `_iterbits` be moved inside of `φ`  / made "free"? I had debated that a lot, but ultimately worried that it would be _too_ trivial without it; I know that there are some truly stellar ideas lurking in golfers' bit-banging capabilities, and would thus make a fun component of the challenge. Is this particular facet something that's already been explored in other challenges and thus not worth re-hashing?

Comment: Given the nature of the challenge, I do agree that it seems reasonable to accept only an array (or blob, or whatever) of bytes rather than bits. But please consider including the result of φ(m) in the test cases. Furthermore, we can't tell for sure which version of CRC32 was used.

Comment: The 1st (or 0th) bit in a byte is the most or least significant one?

Comment: Isn't `array-manipulation` a better tag here than `set-theory`, since the indices of elements matter?

Comment: @pajonk That's a good question (and, on consideration, I agree A.M. is a more appropriate tag), though it reminded me why I'd chosen S.T. in the first place: since the function is only selecting a subset, the output doesn't need to have any ordering! I updated the spec to include this.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the first two test cases, where the number of bits in ```phi(m)``` is greater than 2x the number of elements in ```N```. Probably I'm doing something wrong, but I can't seem to make the odd/even sequence of the given output match the bits of the given phi(m) input...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Good catch! I had slightly miswired the reference bit-unpacking function, which apparently neither I nor any of the reviewers on the Sandbox had noticed. I have updated the reference answer, as well as the test cases given.

Comment: I still don't get the second test case (starts odd, odd, even, even, suggesting 0011 bits = 3, but this doesn't appear as any of the input nibbles): can you check that it's correct?

Comment: Also, just to check, do you really mean "behavior is totally undefined in the event that φ returns something with more bits than **twice** the number of elements in pk", or do you mean "more than **half** the number of elements in pk..."?

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>86</s> <s>83</s> 82 bytes

(or **[64 bytes](https://tio.run/##XZDdaoNAEIXv8xRTiqBlQp0x/tJc584XKC1o0ChYte4GTF/eHoyEUobdZb7Zc3Zmp@V0XOprf7bt0Ls1517@bqpvt3zbm2IcuxvYo1x6pfPq6KcbZ77nOOp5L7p/Kj@W/ChZoLvdM0k00081DVS21mS7k3t2ffY9@BKKTAFTyBQzpUyCXAAERIAETMEUTMEUTMECgXEyk9xNaXXVMNxclenAFDElsPCxAAREIsj8NWQNnHdp@r@fv8pgU1Zz8TV2FTWFaWiqzLWzZJvCUmvIDgN1Q3@hepgAKyqmqbht06IzXvfHKwGHHHPKGBj2GFcSVlxR1gNrxLqm@MDlFw)** with additional `NA` values in output when length of hash result is greater than half the length of the private key N)

```r
function(f,N,d=seq(b<-sapply(f,function(b)b%/%2^(7:0)%%2))*2)N[(d-!b)*!d>sum(N|1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##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)

Input is an array `f` of single-byte integers (representing the output of the hash function phi) and an array `N` (representing the ordered array from which to select a subset).

```r
G=function(f,N){            # G is function with args f=array of bytes, N=array of values
  bits=                     # calculate the bits of f:
    sapply(f,function(b)    #   for each byte b in f
      b%/%2^(7:0)%%2)       #   get its bits
  d=seq(bits)               # define d as 1..number of bits 
  N[                        # now output the elements of N given by indices:
    (d*2-1+bits)            #   d*2-1+bits (these are the indices from the bytes of f)
             *!d>sum(N|1)/2 #   multiplied by zero (FALSE) for bits that exceed the length of N
    ]
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't taking input as `raw` be shorter? Then `rawToBits` with `rev`? I started working on it, but got discouraged by the first two test cases...

Comment: Appears to be 2 bytes shorter: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jRcdP0y9aI7FYL680N7UoM1kjx0a3KLVMoyixPCTfKbOkWAPES9EEAm2NYtvi1EKNHE1NLSNdQ00txWK74tJcDb8aQ019o9j/aRrJGYlFIflBieUaSjEVhilKmjoKhlbGRppcaFIpJiDpmAqLZLiS/wA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @pajonk Nice!  That deserves it's own answer, and you can also [save a couple more bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jRcdP0y9aI7FYLyW/NCknVSPHRrcotUyjKLE8JN8ps6RYA8RL0QQCbY1i2@LUQo0cTS0jTV1DTS3FYrvi0lwNvxpDzdj/aRrJGYlFIflBieUaSjEVhilKmjoKhlbGRppcaFIpJiDpmAqLZLiS/wA), too...

Comment: @pajonk (and [some more bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jRcdP0y9aQ0Mjx0a3KLVMoyixPCTfKbOkWAPES9EEAjsDTW2NYtvi1EKNHE0tI01dQ00txWK74tJcDb8aQ83Y/2kayRmJRSH5QYnlGkoxFYYpSpo6CoZWxkaaXGhSKSYg6ZgKi2S4kv8A) saved with a bit of re-arrangement...)

Comment: Thanks, nice golfs. Golfing on mobile is not as easy as I thought... ;-)

Comment: Take the 64-byte, then! That behavior is undefined; an exception would be preferable for the real-world, but undefined values are also fine for undefined behavior in golf!

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>80</s> <s>62</s> <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```r
function(d,N)N[seq(b<-rawToBits(rev(d)))*2-rev(b<1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZFPT4MwHIbv@xTNvLSmM/Qv04yLH2AHs5t4gJZGkgVmYY5vjy/RMF0yd/iF8vQNPG8bx5CN4di4vm4b6vmWbV@76oOWm1UsTrv2ue47GqtP6hlj93I1LcuNYG9joO69iLv2pTjRZT54nQ/C58PaLRkn4slqtlgU@z29nSNZRhyVnGhODCdrTh6xg3ehMCAixYBJgUFIWgxiEkwhp8AUcgo5Baanb4FpMJ0yiFxISJsPpoQEns7@L3wl@y0NIThCJz1L67O0TC6kJ8HkirT4kbaTNE4COYOcwQ8McgbMglkwq6ZSd74OoYpV05O6ORx70h6mW@xIaCPB7aF10T1gQR1NeMLmmjNPhhB@0T@9hZ@7jl8)

As per OP we don't need to handle cases when bits from `φ` select elements outside `N`.

*-4 bytes thanks to [@Dominic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)*

```r
function               # a function
        (d,            # taking first input as raw bytes (one of R data types)
           N)          # and N as a vector
N[                     # subset N at following indices
  seq(                 # make sequence 1..length(l) - default behaviour for seq on a vector is seq_along
      b<-              # assign the following to b
     rawToBits(rev(d)) # get bits from bytes in d (in reverse order)
                       # as rawToBits returns bits from the least-significant first, we need to reverse the vector on output (to make most-significant bit first - later on), but also on input (to preserve byte order)
                   )*2 # double every index
-rev(b<1)              # decrement corresponding indices when bit is off (taking rev here to save parentheses)
                       # comparison is the shortest operator casting from raw to something `-` will handle
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>56</s>  55 bytes

Expects `(N)(b)`, where `b` is `φ(m)`.

```javascript
N=>b=>N.filter((_,i)=>((q=b[i>>4])>>7.5-i/2%8^~i)&q>=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHRToMwFIbv9xTnRtfGrmspLTOGJrrpJS9A0MAc2mWOjS1mXuir4ykYtiyO5BD4@f/znR6W@We@m9dusx@tq9dFU8ZNEtsitgkv3Wq/qAl5YY7GlpBtXKTO2jCj1kZcj9w4uJo8/zh6vbWxoE0CMaSc8/u6zr@ICWnGP/KNz4OjEFtwcAOS3g0G6QAgFYdZyEAc5MzfJ9OMQXeNxxAwwG@awYTBLQOJ71JhoSIjLNQCiYWmwGChLUBNoU@hptCn0KdQC30v1ELUwqgD@4w46IcW3D5PDeIRjE2Rg1J0BIdHcCDOwB4iLoDlH9h4MJ4GfRp9GgEafRo1g5pBzajvbjIh/DRC9MvoV9JNpvvJ5IWVoBbobrJ2JbJr/PR01vJs16bdtRQnZzZdUs4y@D/Zj3SaVG0yG/Cyqh/z@Tsp/K@fV@tdtVrwVfVGSpJQUlC@rNyaDBkMKaXNLw)

#### Commented

```javascript
N =>                // outer function taking N[]
b =>                // inner function taking b[]
N.filter((_, i) =>  // for each entry at position i in N[]:
  (                 //
    (               //
      q =           //   let q be the byte from b[]
        b[i >> 4]   //   at index floor(i / 16)
    ) >>            //   right shift it by
    7.5 - i / 2 % 8 //   0 to 7 positions, according to floor(i / 2) mod 8
    ^ ~i            //   XOR the result with i inverted
  )                 //
  &                 //   isolate the least significant bit, or force zero
  q >= 0            //   if q is undefined
)                   // end of filter()
```